# Javascript SDK get facebook friendlist member

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-fql

I luckly get some ununderstandable response when trying to get friendlist from a facebook account, this is what i got when console.log:

```
 #v_3 { __wrapped=#v_3, __observableEvents={...}, name="v_3", more...}

The method FB.Data.query:toString is not officially supported by Facebook and access to it will soon be removed.
```

Here is my code for login and get user's friendlist member:

```
    FB.init({ appId:'my_appid' });

    // fetch the status on load
    FB.getLoginStatus(handleSessionResponse);

    $('#login').bind('click', function() {
        FB.login(handleSessionResponse);
    });

    $('#logout').bind('click', function() {
        FB.logout(handleSessionResponse);
    });

    // handle a session response from any of the auth related calls
    function handleSessionResponse() {
        FB.api('/me', function(response) {
            var access_token = FB.getAuthResponse()['accessToken'];
            console.log(access_token);
            console.log(response);
            var friends = FB.Data.query('SELECT uid, flid FROM friendlist_member WHERE flid IN (SELECT flid FROM friendlist WHERE owner=me())');
            console.log(friends);

            $('#user-info').html(response.id + ' - ' + response.name);
        });
    }
```

Anyone has exprienced the same issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, there is a much better way to get the friendlist of a user:

```
FB.api('me/friends', function(response) {
   console.log(response);
}
```

If you really want to use FQL (which is not a good way in this case), it is explained how to use FQL with the JavaScript SDK in this thread: [How can I execute a FQL query with Facebook Graph API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2721927/how-can-i-execute-a-fql-query-with-facebook-graph-api)

The correct FQL call to get the friends would be this one:

```
SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1=me()
```

> https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/

Comment: i tried ur link to get friend list with fql but still getinng 0 data

Comment: fql is very buggy, if there is a way with the graph api (see my code) you should always use it. zero data could also mean that you are missing the correct permission though, but if it works with the graph api, it should also work with fql.

Comment: btw, i think you are using the wrong FQL call in your code. don´t mix "friends" with "lists". i will edit my answer to include the correct fql.

Comment: there is no problem with ur code, but if I try to do the same with FQL it doesnt work.`FB.api('fql', { q: 'SELECT name FROM friendlist WHERE owner=me()' }, 
     function(response){
      console.log(response);
    });` I was thinking about getting friends online_presence, which permision is required here, im not sure how to implement that in graph api nor FQL yet.

Comment: look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1795934/how-to-get-list-of-online-friends-using-fql-with-facebook-api

Comment: I managed to get online_presence by using `SELECT online_presence FROM user WHERE uid in (select uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()`, but all showing null, i have extend permission `{scope: 'read_stream,publish_stream,offline_access'}`

Comment: sorry for bothering! i got it fixed, added `friends_online_presence`

Comment: btw, "offline_access" is deprecated since many months and will be deactivated very soon. i would not use it anymore.